# Still Getting Errors After Applying All I've Read About the Error 02270

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

I'm creating a couple of Tables for an assignment.

So I created a `Gardener` Table and an `Offering` Table, with all the appropriate data types and NULL statuses, as well as the Primary Key constraint for each. In the `Gardener` table I've included `offeringID`, and vice versa.

When I try to add Foreign Key constraint `offeringID` to the `Gardener` Table I get an error.

After checking online, I realized I had forgotten to make `offeringID` and `gardenerID` in each other's tables UNIQUE, hence I altered table to add uniqueness.

Tried adding Foreign Key constraint and I get the same error. I reckon I may be understanding something wrongly, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

```
Create Table Gardener
(gardenerID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
offeringID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT gardener_pk PRIMARY KEY(gardenerID)
);

Create Table Offering
(offeringID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
gardenerID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT offering_pk PRIMARY KEY(offeringID)
);

Alter Table Gardener
add CONSTRAINT offering_fk FOREIGN KEY(offeringID)
REFERENCES Offering(offeringID);

Alter Table Gardener
add Unique(offeringID);

Alter Table Offering
add Unique(gardenerID);
```

This is the error:

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

Cause: A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list 
for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
```

Like, I still don't get it. Isn't `offeringID` a Primary Key hence pointing to it from `Gardener` shouldn't be an issue still?

Comment: Not necessarily related to your error, I wanted to point out that I suspect something is wrong with your thinking. The number of situations where you would make two tables that each have a unique reference to the other table, is incredibly limited - most of the time where you want a 1:1 relationship between two tables you would instead just put all the data in one table. On most relationships one table is the parent, one table is the child, and multiple child records can exist per parent record

Comment: If I was making a system where there were gardeners and gardens and each gardener can quote on multiple gardens and each garden can have multiple gardeners quote on it, I would have a Gardeners table, a Gardens table and a Quotes table. Quotes would have 3 columns: GardenerId, GardenId (both form the primary key) and QuoteAmount. Quotes.GardenerId references Gardeners.Id, and Quotes.GardenId references Gardens.Id. Neither Gardeners nor Gardens has any reference at all to quotes because they are parent tables and quotes is the child. This allows Gardeners and Gardens to have no quotes at all

Comment: I was actually thinking that. Gardener-Offering is in a 1:M relationship, so I shouldn't be having an FK in Gardener right? Just in offering. I was doing things under the impression that so long as they were related both sides needed an FK.

Comment: True, the 1 side to the relationship should NOT have a key to the M side of the relationship because it means the M side has to exist before the 1 can exist. The 1 side has the primary key, the M side has the foreign key that reserves the 1 primary key. If these things were parents the primary side is the parent - one parent has 0, 1, many children but the parent has to exist first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to add a a foreign key constraint for `offering.offeringID` column within the `Gardener` table, whereas that column has no `unique/primary key` key when you try to add a foreign key. i.e. operation stops at the 3rd command.

So, just exchange the order of commands as :

```
Alter Table Gardener 
add Unique(offeringID); -- should be prior to the below command

Alter Table Gardener
add CONSTRAINT offering_fk FOREIGN KEY(offeringID)
REFERENCES Offering(offeringID);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=daa926e8ef9d70be8baddde77ada5e53)</kbd>

Comment: Hey! I actually just figured the whole thing out. Decided to just drop every Table I already did and made sure all the necessary attributes were UNIQUE from the start rather than adding it after. Apparently it worked.

Comment: @darkien well, nice :)

Comment: @darkien the proper way to say thanks is to mark the answer as correct/solution

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Oh sorry, I'm still kind of new to using this platform. Marked! :D

Comment: hey, no worries @darkien we're here to look out for you  - welcome to both SO & Oracle :)